# Stripe : Non-inr currency payment failing for india issued cards

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, currency

Integrating stripe custom flow payment in my application.

According to Indian regulation india issued cards require denomination in 'inr' .

But my business shows the user payment in  'usd'.

So Is there a stripe api which converts payment amount from usd to inr prior to creating the 'Payment Intent'.

Or else I will have to use an external currency converting api which are mostly paid.

(This should ideally be done by stripe itself but it fails the transaction.)

Comment: You do have to convert it yourself yes. But it's usually a bad idea to just take your USD price and convert it straight to INR. You should _choose_ your local price, based on your local competitors and different purchasing power(look up "big mac index") in different countries.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting your currency?

You may wish to refer to https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#presentment-currencies and set the currency to `IN`. As an abstract...

> Stripe users can process charges in the following list of currencies with these exceptions:
>
> You can charge American Express cards only in INR and USD.
> Domestic charges can only be in INR.
> International payments are allowed only in non-INR currencies.
> These currencies apply to card payments—other payment methods are often tied to a specific currency.

Since you're creating `PaymentIntent`, then pass in the 3-letter ISO currency code (i.e. `inr` in the `currency` field: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-currency